# I recieve a white page when the second condition is true in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a condition where the code checks if a phone number exists in DB and then the username.

```
$query1 = "SELECT `Phone` FROM `NewUser` WHERE Phone=?";
$query2 = "SELECT `Username` FROM `NewUser` WHERE Username=?";

// checks the Phone number existence
if($stmt = $LINK->prepare($query1)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Phone);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->store_result();
        $Phone_check= "";         
        $stmt->bind_result($Phone_check);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){
            
            echo "That Phone already exists.";
            die();
        }
    }
}

// checks the Username existence
elseif($stmt2 = $LINK->prepare($query2)){
    $stmt2->bind_param("s", $User);
    if($stmt2->execute()){
        $stmt2->store_result();
        $User_check= "";         
        $stmt2->bind_result($User_check);
        $stmt2->fetch();
        if ($stmt2->num_rows == 1){
            echo "That Username already exists.";
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

if the first condition is true I get **That phone already exists** but if the second condition occurs I get a white page.

When I swap the conditions then I get **"That Username already exists."**

Comment: Why do you use an `elseif`, instead of a normal `if`, at the beginning of the second condition? Also: I would do this after both conditions: `echo "Phone and Username do not exist";`. That way you will, at least, know the code didn't fail somewhere.

Comment: issue with your if condition ,$stmt = $LINK->prepare($query1) always return true ,so else if never reached

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments `if($stmt = $LINK->prepare($query1))` will return true regardless of whether the record exists or not. You need to remove all these `if` statements and simplify your code.

If you do not need to fetch the data into PHP to use it for something else, then there is absolutely no reason to fetch it. You can just check if the row exists with SQL. Since both columns belong to the same table you can do it in a single statement, too.

```
$stmt = $LINK->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `NewUser` WHERE Phone=? OR Username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $Phone, $User);
$stmt->execute();   
$stmt->bind_result($exists);
$stmt->fetch();
if ($exists) {   
    echo "The phone number or the username already exists.";
    die();
}
```